# LLM model is very slow

Tags: python, machine-learning, large-language-model, llama

I'm running a 34b [LLM model](https://huggingface.co/Phind/Phind-CodeLlama-34B-v2) on an nvidia g5.8xlarge instance (1 Nvidia A10G GPU, 24GB GPU RAM, 32 vCPU,    128GB RAM)

Here is the code for the inference

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer,LlamaForCausalLM, AutoConfig, AutoModelForCausalLM
from accelerate import infer_auto_device_map, init_empty_weights
import torch

model_path = "Phind/Phind-CodeLlama-34B-v2"

model = LlamaForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_path, device_map="auto", offload_folder="offload", torch_dtype=torch.float16, offload_state_dict = True)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_path)

def generate_one_completion(prompt: str):
    tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
    inputs = tokenizer(prompt, return_tensors="pt", truncation=True, max_length=4096)

    # Generate
    generate_ids = model.generate(inputs.input_ids.to("cuda"), max_new_tokens=384, do_sample=True, top_p=0.75, top_k=10, temperature=0.1)
    completion = tokenizer.batch_decode(generate_ids, skip_special_tokens=True, clean_up_tokenization_spaces=False)[0]
    completion = completion.replace(prompt, "").split("\n\n\n")[0]

    return completion

text = "Hello, you are you?"
print(generate_one_completion(text))
```

1. Loading checkpoint shards - this takes 4 minutes. How can this be sped up ?
2. Even simple inferences take 60+ seconds. Code infilling/prompting takes 10+ minutes. Can this be sped on this ec2 instance ?

Comment: did you find any useful answers? i'm having the same issue and afraid my GPU is not being utilized (with how slow this all is)